# No Maximum Bitrate H264 codec

Tags: premiere, encoding, h.264, bitrate

I am trying to export a video with a low bitrate. Regardless of what I set as the target bitrate, the video always is exported with the highest possible bitrate. This occurs whether I use VBR or CBR.

The option to set a Maximum Bitrate is not present. Why?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Video Production Stack Exchange! 
I presume this is Adobe Premiere Pro?

Comment: Yes, thank you.